# How to set up 2FA using LinOTP and FreeRadius on Linux (RHEL 8)

Tags: ssh, freeradius

I need to set up 2FA for user login methods to VMs (i.e. SSH, RDP..etc) and would need to do this using LinOTP with auth module FreeRaduis. Can you please guide me how to set up LinOTP on RHEL machine with FreeRadius as an auth module for my LDAP users.

**Things that i have tried:**
I have tried exploring the content on LinOTP official documentation to install LinOTP server on RHEL but couldn't find a way to install FreeRadius on RHEL. Documentation has steps for CentOS/Debian buster.

https://linotp.org/doc/2.9.1/part-installation/auth-modules/index.html
Can you please help me guide how to set this up.